# How dows eager loading work for relations?

Tags: laravel

I have read the docs I got that if call relation like: `users()->author->name` it sends another one request in db each time.

But if to call using `User()::with("author")` it will be loaded eager.

Therefore I try to understand how does it work if I call sometimes the method `Auth::user()` in controller:

```
public function controllerMethod(){
  Auth::user()->tags();
  /// Some logic 

  Auth::user()->id;
  // Some logic
 
  Auth::user()->tags();
}
```

Does it create a three the same requets in db or two the same and one additional with tags?

If yeas how toad it in global score because I need to get `Auth::user()` object everywehere in app to show the users fields.

Comment: Afaik it won't do 3 different requests. But you could try it yourself and test it. It's easy. Just install debugbar in your project `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev` and return the user to a view after your tests. There, in left bottom side of the page you will see Laravel's logo. Click it and open DB tab. There you'll be able to see the queries you did and will tell you if there is duplicated sql queries and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User()::with()` is actually an error:

> Call to undefined function User()

The correct syntax would be `User::with()`

`with()` tells Laravel's Eloquent which relationship(s) to include **when the query is executed**. On its own, `User::with('author')` will not do much. When you use a closure, like `->get()` or `->first()`, it will execute a subquery, like:

```
SELECT * FROM authors WHERE user_id IN (...)
```

That `IN (...)` clause will change if you're loading a single `User` via `->first()`, or multiple `User` instances via `->get()`, but will make it so `->author` doesn't need to call a new Database Query. Each `$user->author` property will be filled with an `Author` instance, or `null` (if that `User` doesn't have an `Author`, etc.)

Here's a quick example:

```
// Executes a single query to load each `User`
// Total Queries: 1
$users = User::get();

// Executes a new query on each loop
// Total Queries: 0 - ∞ (depends on number of loaded `User` instances)
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $user->author->name;
}

// Executes a single Query to load each `User`, then a single subquery to load each `Author`
// Total Queries: 2
$users = User::with('author')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $user->author->name;
}
```

---

When you call `auth()->user()`, that returns a single `User` instance, which has already been loaded from the Database. Calling `auth()->user()->author` will execute a new Query, since the `User` returned via `auth()->user()` didn't include `->with('author')`.

If you want to Eager Load a relationship on a `User` that has already been loaded from the Database, you'd call `->load('author')`:

```
// Load the `User` instance from the database for the Authenticated User
$user = auth()->user();
// Executes the subquery `SELECT * FROM authors WHERE user_id = ?`
$user->load('author');
$user->author->name;
// Total Queries: 2
```

One catch, if you use `->author()` (with the `()`), it will execute a new Database query, even if you've already called `->load('author')` (or `->with('author')`):

```
$user = auth()->user();
$user->load('author'); // Subquery
$user->author()->first()->name; // ANOTHER Subquery
// Total Queries: 3
```

So the long and short of it is that `->with()` will make accessing the relationship as a property, `->author` (property) vs `->author()->first()` (method), **not include another Subquery**. If you omit `->with('author')`, then **both `->author` and `->author()->first()` will perform a Subquery**.

Comment: Thank you a lot, so if UserModel has relations DoctorModel and ClinicModel does it mean that by default when I call Auth::user() the doctor, clinic subqueries are not execute until I use with()? and ->

Comment: That is correct  Eager loading for a single `User` instance is generally not required, since as soon as you access them, via `->author`, _then_ they are loaded. There are use cases, like `auth()->user()->toJson()` will not include `'author': [...]`, while `$user = auth()->user()`, `$user->load('author')`, then `$user->toJson()` will include it (since it has been loaded onto the `->author` property)